# Can I have a part of a scrollable Listview (implemented using hashmap) non-scrollable?

Tags: android

Im trying to make a list to enter the marks of students. 
I have an xml layout file which has the name of student as a textview and marks of 5 subjects as edittexts.
Then I have another xml layout file which has a listview which is horizontally scrollable.
Now in the java file Im using Hashmap to duplicate this layout for multiple students.
I have the entire list horizontally scrollable.
If I scroll left or right, I want all the rows to be scrolled together with the names being static horizontally.
But I want only the marks to be scrollable. I want the name of student to be static. 
I tried to make the textview used 4 name as horizontallyscrollable="false". Doesn't help.
Need help.